# Does each account need a unique email address?

Tags: ps4

Our children are all users and are being asked to enter emails in order to log in. They don't even have their own email accounts so can we just use one email (an adult one)?

Answer (score 8):

Your account as an adult should be the main account, under which you can create sub-accounts for children. This will require only one email address.

The process is outlined in [Sony's Playstation 4 User Guide](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/subaccount.html).

To summarize, to create sub accounts, this is the process:

> Select [Parental Controls] > [Sub Account Management] > [Create New Sub Account], and then follow the screens to create a new sub account.

You can also set parental controls there.